# Php перевести строку в число с плавающей точкой

Tags: php, float

С бдя получаю `payload = "0,01". Мне нужно перевести эту строку в` float`, НО

```js
$payload = "0,01";
dump((float) $payload); // 0.0
dump(flotval($payload)); // 0.0
dump((float) number_format(
  (float) $maxEarnings,
  2,
  ".",
  ""
)); // 0.0
```

Как решить эту проблему

Comment: Ну дык тебе даже в выводе показывають - __точка__ должна быть разделителем целой и дробной части, а не запятая.

Comment: Оу, да не заметил, но всё равно. Если в `number_format`  поменять `"."` на `","`, то результат тот же - `0,0`.Или вы имели в виду изменить `"0,01"` на `"0.01"`?

Comment: `$payload = "0.01";`